# How do you use and activate Node.js on a Chromebook?

Tags: node.js, chromebook

I've been looking all over the internet to figure this out, but it always comes up with results for "How to Install Node.JS". What I'm looking for isn't how to install it, but how to actually use it once it's installed on my Chromebook. Any help would be much appreciated.

*(Chromebook is a Lenovo S33 with a 32-bit)*

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/1370187/how-do-you-reach-the-chromebook-terminal?hl=en ?

Comment: I think you cant. Perhaps you are lucky with compiling it from source. (or this: https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

### To use node.js in the terminal:

Once you've installed node and npm, you can run the `node` command in your terminal and type any node.js code in the following prompt. Press ctrl D when you are ready to exit. For example:

```
node
Welcome to Node.js vX.X.X
Type ".help" for more information.
> var x = 0;
undefined
> console.log(x)
0
```

---

### To run a node.js file:

You can run the `node` command followed by whatever file you want to run. For example: `node myfile.js`